# How to get particular items from particular object onclick of listview in xamarin c#

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin

I want to retrieve a particular item(that is Heading and Subheading items) on click of particular row from object.i have used this code

> var selectedTableItem = e.Parent.GetItemAtPosition(e.Position);

below is code.Here i am getting whole object but how to get items in object?.Any help is appreciated

```
        List<TableItem> tableItems = new List<TableItem>();
        ListView listView;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.HomeScreen);
            listView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.List);
            EditText _filterText = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editInp);
           tableItems.Add(new TableItem() { Heading = "Vegetables", SubHeading = "65 items" });
            tableItems.Add(new TableItem() { Heading = "Fruits", SubHeading = "17 items" });


            _filterText.TextChanged += (object sender, Android.Text.TextChangedEventArgs e) => {
                // filter on text changed
                var searchTerm = _filterText.Text;
                var updatedTableItems = tableItems.Where(
                    // TODO Fill in your search, for example:
                    tableItem => tableItem.Heading.ToLower().Contains(searchTerm.ToLower()) ||
                                 tableItem.SubHeading.ToLower().Contains(searchTerm.ToLower())
                ).ToList();
                var filteredResultsAdapter = new HomeScreenAdapter(this, updatedTableItems);
                listView.Adapter = filteredResultsAdapter;
            };
            listView.Adapter = new HomeScreenAdapter(this, tableItems);

            listView.ItemClick += OnListItemClick;
        }

        protected void OnListItemClick(object sender, Android.Widget.AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {
            var selectedTableItem = e.Parent.GetItemAtPosition(e.Position);
             }
    }
}



public class TableItem
    {

        public string Heading { get; set; }
        public string SubHeading { get; set; }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
void OnListItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
var listView = sender as ListView;
var t = tableItems[e.Position];
Android.Widget.Toast.MakeText(this, t.Heading, Android.Widget.ToastLength.Short).Show();
}

//Make a toast with the item name just to show it was clicked
```

Comment: it shows error says home screen doesnot contain filteredResultsAdapter,what is the reason .i even made it as global variable but nothing is working.can you show me full code please